# choose solr documents where one field is great than another

Tags: solr

What is the syntax for choosing solr documents where one field is great than another?

More specifically, this is for two fields that contains dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding all docs where date_A>date_B is not supported.

If you are only comparing data_A and date_B, then you could index another field
date_a_greater_than_date_b:true for documents when date_A>date_B.

Answer (score 19):

I found this question looking for the same thing. As it turns out, you can filter by field comparisons using a [filter query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq), particularly frange and sub.

`frange` can take a lower bound `l` or an upper bound `u`, or both.
Optional values `incl` and `incu` inform the filter if the boundaries are inclusive or not.

`sub` subtracts the literal numbers or document fields.

So the answer is to add a filter that accepts only those documents where A minus B is greater than zero. Set the lower bound to 0, omit the upper bound, and set `incl` to false to exclude the lower bound itself (to remove documents where A==B)

`fq={!frange l=0 incl=false}sub(A,B)`

URL Encoded: `fq=%7B!frange+l%3D0+incl%3Dfalse%7Dsub(A%2CB)`